# django-channels systemd daphne

Tags: django, systemd

На протяжении нескольких часов пытаюсь решить проблему с загрузкой переменных окружения, при использовании [Daphne](https://github.com/django/daphne)

До этого использовал практически такой же конфиг при использовании [Gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/), и всё прекрасно работало.

Изначально пытался делать так же как в конфиге `gunicorn`: `EnvironmentFile=/var/www/gglobal/.envvars`, но так получал ошибку:

```
Jun 26 17:37:47 p435061.kvmvps daphne[14073]: 2017-06-26 17:37:47,542 DEBUG    get 'RDS_HOSTNAME' casted as 'None' with default '<NoValue>'
Jun 26 17:37:47 p435061.kvmvps daphne[14073]: 2017-06-26 17:37:47,543 DEBUG    get 'RDS_PORT' casted as 'None' with default '<NoValue>'
Jun 26 17:37:47 p435061.kvmvps daphne[14073]: 2017-06-26 17:37:47,543 DEBUG    get 'REDIS_ENDPOINT_ADDRESS' casted as 'None' with default '<NoValue>'
Jun 26 17:37:47 p435061.kvmvps daphne[14073]: 2017-06-26 17:37:47,543 DEBUG    get 'REDIS_PORT' casted as 'None' with default '<NoValue>'
Jun 26 17:37:47 p435061.kvmvps daphne[14073]: 2017-06-26 17:37:47,544 DEBUG    get 'DJANGO_SENTRY_DSN' casted as 'None' with default 'https://56bb387ee6ef4e7b
Jun 26 17:37:47 p435061.kvmvps daphne[14073]: 2017-06-26 17:37:47,544 DEBUG    get 'DJANGO_SENTRY_CLIENT' casted as 'None' with default 'raven.contrib.django.
Jun 26 17:37:47 p435061.kvmvps daphne[14073]: 2017-06-26 17:37:47,544 DEBUG    get 'DJANGO_SENTRY_LOG_LEVEL' casted as '<class 'int'>' with default '20'
Jun 26 17:37:47 p435061.kvmvps daphne[14073]: 2017-06-26 17:37:47,544 DEBUG    get 'DJANGO_SENTRY_LOG_LEVEL' casted as '<class 'int'>' with default '20'
Jun 26 17:37:47 p435061.kvmvps daphne[14073]: 2017-06-26 17:37:47,545 DEBUG    get 'DJANGO_ADMIN_URL' casted as 'None' with default '<NoValue>'
```

НО ПРИ ВСЁМ ПРИ ЭТОМ, СЕРВИС СТАРТУЕТ!

а nginx error log ругается, на отсутствие `*.sock` файла:

```
2017/06/26 17:47:51 [crit] 12682#12682: *59 connect() to unix:/var/www/project/project.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 5.152.1.201, server: mydomain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://unix:/var/www/project/project.sock:/", host: "mydomain.com"
```

С тем вариантом, как представлено ниже, получаю чуть другую ошибку:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the DJANGO_SECRET_KEY
>   environment variable

Затем я решил попробовать написать небольшой bash скрипт, который бы явно экспортировал перемнные:

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line"  ]]; do
        export $line
        echo exporting $line
done < "$1"
```

И запускать этот скрипт перед  при помощи `ExecStartPre`, но результата тоже не дало. Точнее результат такой же, как и в предыдущем случае, ругается на не экспортированный `DJANGO_SECRET_KEY`.

Вот `daphne.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=daphne daemon
After=network.target


[Service]
ExecStartPre=-bash /tmp/env.sh  /var/www/project/.envvars
Environment=DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=config.settings.production
User=project
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/project
ExecStart=/var/www/venv/bin/daphne -b unix:/var/www/project/project.sock  config.asgi:channel_layer -v2

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

а вот `gunicorn.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target


[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/var/www/project/.envvars
User=project
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/project
ExecStart=/var/www/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/var/www/project/project.sock config.wsgi:application --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='config.settings.production'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Сейчас они отличаются, и можно сказать "сделай так же, как в том. который работает", но так не работает, по этому и пробовал делать по всякому, в том числе методом тыка.

В упор не понимаю, в чём проблема.

У кого есть какие идеи ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот рабочий конфиг:

```
[Unit]
Description=daphne daemon
After=network.target


[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/var/www/gglobal/.envvars
User=gglobal
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/project
ExecStart=/var/www/venv/bin/daphne -u /var/www/gglobal/project.sock  config.asgi:channel_layer -v2

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Чтобы успешно запустить на `unix` сокете, небходимо просто указать путь, без приставки `unix:`, как это было в конфиге `gunicorn`